# Calling an Objective C function from a C function passing an array of floats

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, camera

I´m trying to pass a reference of array of floats.
The problem is the call, because I´am developing for c but I want to make a call to an Objective C Function, Could anyone help me? How can I make the call?
There you have the code:

```
bool VideoCamera_Camera(float *buffer) {
    [VideoCameraBinded VideoCamera_CameraUpdateBinded: buffer];
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried it?  What problem did you encounter?

Comment: I agree with Stephen, and additionally, how is the objc method defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that VideoCameraBinded is an instance, and not a class. If I am mistaken, please let me know.

If you have a method defined on VideoCameraBinded's class, something like this:

```
- (void)VideoCamera_CameraUpdateBinded:(float *)buffer {
//...
}
```

then I don't know where your problem is coming from. Are you getting a specific error or some other issue?

Comment: Solved, the problent wasn´t here XD, I was trying to access to the array in a wrong way, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to and can change the Objective-C code, add a C API there.

Otherwise, if you really can't change the Objective-C code you can use the Objective-C runtime directly, but this is discouraged:

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>

objc_msgSend(VideoCameraBinded, // receiver
             sel_registerName("VideoCamera_CameraUpdateBinded:"), // selector
             buffer); // comma separated list of arguments
```

You need to link to an Objective-C runtime library, usually libobjc:

```
$ clang mycode.c -lobjc
$ # or cc if you use GCC
```

---

If the Objective-C method expects an `NSArray *` instead of a `float *`, you can use Core Foundation with `CFArrayRef`. `CFArrayRef` and `NSArray *` are interchangeable, but `CFArrayRef` is a C type so you can use that. Same goes for `CFNumberRef` and `NSNumber *`, see [Apple's documentation on this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

What is the parameter type for `VideoCamera_CameraUpdateBinded:`?

If its NSArray then you have to loop, create an array and send it like any other obj-c method. You'll have to store the floats in some kind of objects (e.g. `NSNumber`).

Otherwise, if the obj-c function is taking a float* then you should be good to go.

BTW, shouldn't you pass a **bufferSize** parameter too?